# How can I retrieve all the local groups for a domain user in C# in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, active-directory

I have a web app (built in C# with .NET Core 3.1) and I need to retrieve a user's local group membership on the web server where the app runs.  The users are domain users and not local ones on that machine and have to provide their domain credentials when they log into the app.  The code I'm having trouble with is as follows:

```
var machineContext  = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("COMPUTERNAME"));
var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(machineContext, userName);
```

*userName* is built up using .NET Core's *IHttpContextAccessor* and works perfectly. I left that code out for brevity.  Using that code to try to build a *PrincipalContext* for the machine, *userPrincipal* is always null. 
 I've been able to get this to sort of work as an alternative:

```
var pc = new PrincipalContext(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName);
var p = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName);
var upn = p.UserPrincipalName;

var currWinIdentity = new System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity(upn);
currWinIdentity.Groups.ToList()
    .ForEach(h =>
    {
        var groupName = h.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
        Console.WriteLine($"{groupName} ({h.Value})");
    });
```

I found that building a *WindowsIdentity* using the user's UPN gets me to a superset of the list of groups I want with the above code.  The problem is that to get this to work -- presumably this is because the *PrincipalContext* I'm building is built as *ContextType.Domain* but that was the only way I could get it to work -- I have to set the app pool in IIS to run as a user that's on the domain, instead of running as the default *ApplicationPoolIdentity* and for some of the client environments I'm going to put this on, that's not going to work.

So, does anyone know how I can fix my code to behave the way I want or is there a better way to get the local groups for a domain user?

Comment: I don't have time to do the research for you, but I do know that you can't run a query against local groups like you can for AD. You can break this up into two steps and look up how to do each: 1. Find all local groups on the current computer, then 2. Find all the members in a local group. Then you can loop through all the groups, and loop through all the members of each group and see if the current user is in it.

Comment: @GabrielLuci I'll see if I can figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me on a WebAPI project using Windows Authentication (.net core 2.1)

```
[HttpGet]

public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
    {
        var username = HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
        var claims = HttpContext.User.Identity;
        var wi = (WindowsIdentity)claims;

        List<String> groupVals = new List<String>();

        foreach(var group in wi.Groups)
        {

            var gn = group.Translate(typeof(NTAccount)).ToString();
            groupVals.Add(gn);
        }
    
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```